# azure SSL Application Gateway with Web APPS

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-web-apps

I am working on setting up the the Azure Application Gateway Web Application Firewall for a Web App hosted on Web Apps with everything behind SSL.

I can get it to work when everything is none SSL using this article
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell

However when I try to Change it to SSL and upload the CER file i cannot get it to show Heathly.
I changed all the references to https, and everything looks correct but i am still stuck

I also tried this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell
with no luck

Any thoughts on what i am missing, need this to work before i can go HA with the solution

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Did you get some error messages ?

Comment: I worked with MS Support on this issue and found that you can set this up using powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the script MS Support worked with me on to make this work

```
# FQDN of the web app
$webappFQDN = "XXX.XXXXX.com"  

# Retrieve an existing application gateway
$gw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "XXXX" -ResourceGroupName "XXXX"

# Define the status codes to match for the probe
$match=New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeHealthResponseMatch -StatusCode 200-399

# Add a new probe to the application gateway
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -name webappprobe-1 -ApplicationGateway $gw -Protocol Https -Path / -Interval 30 -Timeout 120 -UnhealthyThreshold 3 -PickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings -Match $match

# Retrieve the newly added probe
$probe = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -name webappprobe-1 -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Configure an existing backend http settings 

Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name appGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $gw -PickHostNameFromBackendAddress -Port 443 -Protocol https -CookieBasedAffinity Disabled -RequestTimeout 30 -Probe $probe

Exclude these 2 lines
#$authcert = New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate -Name whitelistcert1 -CertificateFile C:\XXXX\XXXX.cer

#Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name appGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $gw  -PickHostNameFromBackendAddress -Port 443 -Protocol Https -CookieBasedAffinity Enabled -AuthenticationCertificates $authcert

# Add the web app to the backend pool
Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -Name appGatewayBackendPool -ApplicationGateway $gw -BackendFqdns $webappFQDN

# Update the application gateway
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
```